# enter sqlplus command in win7 for connect to Oracle database on windows server 2008

Tags: windows, oracle, sqlplus

I enter this command in windows7 for connect to Oracle database on windows server 2008:

```
 sqlplus 'user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))'
```

but it raise this error:

> error: ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error.

I googled and all I find is about check oracle services is started in windows server 2008.
I checked and all oracle services are started.
what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the below things 
1. Can you ping from win 7 machine to Server? If Yes 
2. Check firewall of server. Make disable and test. 
3. If doesn't work then, check listener service. 
You can check it by simply creating tns and ping it. 
tnsping tnsname

If all fine, then please share version info and above result to me. Hope it will be solve. Thanks.

Comment: I disable my antivirus, personal firewall/network traffic filtering part and it work

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the single quotes; they are making the whole string be interpreted as the username, so it will probably prompt for a password and then get the ORA-12560 error.

```
sqlplus user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))
```

or you can still put just the connection description in quotes:

```
sqlplus user/pass@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))'
```

or if you know the service name (which may or may not be the same as the SID) you can use easy connect syntax:

```
sqlplus user/pass@//hostname.network:1521/remote_service_name
```

Even the default port can be omitted, but I prefer to see it.

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/concepts.htm#NETAG186).

Comment: It did not work with error connection timeout. and after that again ask username and password, when I enter raise last error again

Comment: But it fixed the immediate error. Are you sure the hostname and port are correct? Is there a firewall preventing you reaching the port on that host? (Also you can do `sqlplus -l user/.....` to stop it prompting again on failure).